# SQL multiple tables select with conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Let's say I have these four tables in Oracle:

```
+--------------------+----------------------+
|      PROJECTS      |        PHASES        |
+--------------------+----------------------+
| PROJECT_ID integer | PHASE_ID integer     |
|                    | PROJECT_ID integer   |
|                    | PHASE varchar2(50)   |
|                    | WORKING_HOURS number |
+--------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------+-------------------------+
|        TASKS        |        EMPLOYEES        |
+---------------------+-------------------------+
| TASK_ID integer     | EMPLOYEE_ID integer     |
| PHASE_ID integer    | FIRST_NAME varchar2(50) |
| EMPLOYEE_ID integer | LAST_NAME varchar2(50)  |
+---------------------+-------------------------+
```

EDIT 1.
`project.project_id` is a primary key
`phases.phase_id is` primary key
`tasks.task_id is` a primary key
`employess.employee_id` is a primary key
all other references from other tables to the above are foreign keys!

Let's say `PHASES.PHASE` can have values: alpha, beta, olympus, unicorn

I want it to return a list for a specific project_id(lets say project_id=1) with the employees per phase of the project as well as the working hours per phase.

Something like this (not exactly just an example)

```
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+--+
|     alpha      |      beta      |    olympus     |    unicorn     |  |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+--+
| name1 surname1 | name2 surname2 | name1 surname1 | name4 surname4 |  |
| name2 surname2 | name4 surname4 | name2 surname2 |                |  |
| name3 surname3 |                | name4 surname4 |                |  |
| name4 surname4 |                |                |                |  |
| 15             | 240            | 13             | 300            |  |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+--+
```

Can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Yes my bad wrong tag!

Answer (score 0):

You will need foreign keys within your tables. For example, you will need a project_id in your employees table to know on which project each employee is currently working. Or, another table where you map data like this. Then, it is a matter of using well writen where clauses.

Comment: Yes, i forgot to write them but foreign keys and primary keys are set!

Comment: What are they then? What foreign key connects, for example, employees with projects?

Comment: Anythong with same name us connected. For instance PROJECT.PROJECT_ID is connected with PHASES.PROJECT_ID and so on.